# how to set flutter text limit length or overflow effect

Tags: flutter, text

my code here

```
 Text(
                                      seedPost.content!,
                                      softWrap: false,
                                      textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                                      maxLines: 2,
                                      overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                    ),
```

my seedPost.content text here
"hello \n hello \n hello \n hello"

What is shown now is shown like this.

hello

hello

because maxline = 2

I want to look like this.

hello

hello ...more

how to????

Answer (score 0):

Check this plugin. It works that you need: [readmore](https://pub.dev/packages/readmore)